# How can I create a list of the contacts in a household?

Tags: households

How can I create a list of the contacts in a household?  What I want to see is which contacts are currently in a household.  I also cannot see how I can add a person to an already established household.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Relationships to connect individuals to their Household. So if you start from the H/h or from the Individual you should be able to go to the Relationship Tab and click Add Relationship.

On the Rel. Tab of the H/h you should also see any Individuals already related to it.

Comment: if none of that makes sense perhaps you could add some screenshots to your Question